# NoMethodError 'each' on FactoryBot has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

I have a factory which generates a devise user w/ roles within an engine. The User model `has_many :roles through: :roles_users`. I can get the code to work with a `after(:create)` clause but not with the `association:` keyword.

This works:

app/model/myengine/role.rb

```
module MyEngine
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :roles_users
        has_many :roles, through: :roles_users
    end
end
```

spec/factories/roles.rb

```
factory :role, class: "MyEngine::Role" do
    type: { 'admin' }
end
factory :user, class: "MyEngine::User" do
  sequence(:email) { |n| "tester_#{n}@example.com" }
  password { 'xxx' }
  password_confirmation { 'xxx' }      

  after(:create) do |user|
    user.roles << FactoryBot.create(:role)
  end 
end
```

**But this does not** and the test fails with `undefined method 'each' for #<MyEngine::Role:0x0...>` at initialization:

```
factory :user, class: "MyEngine::User" do
  sequence(:email) { |n| "tester_#{n}@example.com" }
  password { 'xxx'}
  password_confirmation { 'xxx' }      
  association: :roles, factory: :role
end
```

**Updated/Edited below:**

The FactoryBot doc is only suggesting the after(:create) hook likely for a reason. From user comments there are two problems with the above code:

- not using a collection
- the object does not exist when the association is being attached

Using the suggestion of @Vasfed the roles association can be assigned directly  using a collection instead of an object:

```
factory :user, class: "MyEngine::User" do
  sequence(:email) { |n| "tester_#{n}@example.com" }
  password { 'xxx'}
  password_confirmation { 'xxx' }      
  roles { [ create(:role) ] }
end
```

As per @ulferts suggestion to use new instead of create:

```
factory :user, class: "MyEngine::User" do
  sequence(:email) { |n| "tester_#{n}@example.com" }
  password { 'xxx'}
  password_confirmation { 'xxx' }      
  roles { [ build(:role) ] }
end
```

Both will produce:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Roles users is invalid
```

As the model has no validation, this seems to point to trouble w/ missing record in the FK table or a failure to find the FK table, likely due to namespace resolution.

Comment: `roles { [ create(:role) ] }` will attempt the create the role right away, even before the user has been created. Try `roles { [ build(:role) ] }` instead. It is also more versatile and supports scenarios where you do not actually want to save the model for performance reasons.

Comment: @ulferts: Thank you for pointing that out. The object not existing at that time makes sense. I still get the same error, but it now i can pinpoint it to a problem with the FK table (which has to have the id of that object, which has not been created yet.)

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you're passing single instance on role to `roles` instead of collection.
FactoryBot has no way of knowing how many roles you want to create for association, so they need to be created manually anyway.

Simplest workaround without after-hooks can be `roles { [ create(:role) ] }`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That makes absolute sense. Trying this approach i run into a validation error against the through table. Instantiating an empty collection works though: roles { [] }. I'll expand my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar issue and was able to sole it with the following:

**user.rb**

```
# Indexes
#  index_users_on_confirmation_token    (confirmation_token) UNIQUE
#  index_users_on_email                 (email) UNIQUE
#  index_users_on_reset_password_token  (reset_password_token) UNIQUE
#  index_users_on_slug                  (slug) UNIQUE
#  index_users_on_unlock_token          (unlock_token) UNIQUE

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many  :user_roles, -> { includes(:role).order(:role_id) },
            inverse_of: :user,
            dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_roles,
                                reject_if: proc { |attributes|
                                  attributes['role_id'].blank?
                                }

  has_many  :roles,
            through: :user_roles,
            inverse_of: :user_roles

  validates :first_name,
            presence: true

  validates :last_name,
            presence: true

  validates :email,
            presence: true

  validates :user_roles,
            presence: true
end
```

**user_role.rb**

```
# Indexes
#  index_user_roles_on_role_id              (role_id)
#  index_user_roles_on_user_id              (user_id)
#  index_user_roles_on_user_id_and_role_id  (user_id,role_id) UNIQUE

# Foreign Keys
#  fk_rails_...  (role_id => roles.id)
#  fk_rails_...  (user_id => users.id)

class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :user,
              inverse_of: :user_roles

  belongs_to  :role,
              inverse_of: :user_roles


  validates :user,
            presence: true

  validates :role,
            presence: true
end
```

**role.rb**

```
# Indexes
#  index_roles_on_name  (name) UNIQUE

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many  :user_roles,
            autosave: true,
            inverse_of: :role,
            dependent: :nullify

  has_many  :users,
            through: :user_roles,
            inverse_of: :user_roles
end
```

**factories/user.rb**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email(name: [first_name, last_name].join(' ')) }
    password { 'password123!' }

    trait :approver do
      before(:create) do |user|
        user.user_roles << build(:user_role, :approver_role)
      end
    end

    trait :manager do
      before(:create) do |user|
        user.user_roles << build(:user_role, :manager_role)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**factories/user_role.rb**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user_role do
    user
    role

    trait :approver_role do
      role { create(:role, :approver) }
    end

    trait :manager_role do
      role { create(:role, :manager) }
    end
  end
end
```

**factories/role.rb**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :role
    trait :approver do
      to_create do |instance|
        instance.attributes = Role.find_or_create_by!({
          name: 'approver'
        }).attributes

        instance.instance_variable_set('@new_record', false)
      end
    end

    trait :manager do
      to_create do |instance|
        instance.attributes = Role.find_or_create_by!({
          name: 'manager',
        }).attributes

        instance.instance_variable_set('@new_record', false)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**user_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.describe User do
  describe 'create' do
    context 'a user with the approver role' do
      subject(:approver_user) { create(:user, :approver) }

      it 'creates a user which has the approver role' do
        expect(approver_user).to be_kind_of(User)
        expect(approver_user.roles.count).to eq(1)
        expect(approver_user.roles.first.name).to eq('approver')
      end
    end

    context 'a user with the approver & manager role' do
      subject(:approver_user) { create(:user, :approver, :manager) }

      it 'creates a user with both approver & manager roles' do
        expect(approver_user).to be_kind_of(User)
        expect(approver_user.roles.count).to eq(2)
        expect(approver_user.roles.first.name).to eq('approver')
        expect(approver_user.roles.last.name).to eq('manager')
      end
    end
  end
end
```